# How can I serve a stand-alone static app through Django

Tags: django, apache, django-views, django-templates

We're using django for authentication, user management, site content etc, but we have a JS tool that needs to be behind django auth as well. The tool is an html page that pulls in a couple dozen static files through relative paths in the html page (src="./someJSfile.js").

The problem is I can't figure out how to serve the html file through django but keep the relative paths intact. I can create an apache alias to that directory so that the relative paths are intact, but then the html is served through apache and bypasses auth. I would like to be able to have the html file served through a django view so that auth works, and also keep the static files in the same directory.

Is there some apache magic where I can have the html served through django but have the static served through apache using an alias, while keeping the html and static in the same directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could serve it as a server side file and embed your entire JavaScript file’s code inside script tags. The server side file should redirect to login page automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had thought about that, but I'd like to keep the directory and file structure of the JS intact as well - its several files of custom code and a couple of libraries.

Comment: Don’t know if it’s possible. In googling I somehow came up with this https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/

Comment: If I could Alias only certain file types using regex or something that would work, like Alias *.js /path/to/*.js